# Spring MongoDB: how to use DateOperators.DateDiff in ProjectionOperation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have projection:

```
 ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project()
                .and(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromString("$requiredDate")).as("requiredDate") //date
                .and(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromString("$currentDate")).as("currentDate") //date
                .and(DateOperators.DateDiff.diffValueOf("currentDate", "DAYS").toDateOf("requiredDate")).as("diff") //not working
```

I'm trying to retrive difference in days between currentDate and requiredDate, but last line end with error:

```
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 31325 (Location31325): 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unknown expression $dateDiff' on server localhost:60637. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1706998440, "i": 2}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unknown expression $dateDiff", "code": 31325, "codeName": "Location31325", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1706998440, "i": 2}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}}
```

In docs there is:

```
/**
 * Add the number of {@literal units} from a {@literal field} to a {@link #toDate(Object) start date}.
 *
 * @param fieldReference must not be {@literal null}.
 * @param unit must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return new instance of {@link DateAdd}.
 */
public static DateDiff diffValueOf(String fieldReference, String unit) {
    return diffValue(Fields.field(fieldReference), unit);
}
```

But I couldn't find any example on how to use this method. Unfortunately "unit" param is String, so I'm only guessing it's "DAYS", because there is no documentation and usage examples anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach is the following:

```
.and(DateOperators.DateDiff
                          .diffValue("currentDate", "day")
                          .toDate("requiredDate").as("diff"));
```

In the end it is going to be transformed to MongoQuery so the documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/) might help you a bit more.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately: 'append(java.lang.Object)' has protected access in 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AbstractAggregationExpression'